# Open world game state saving Android

Tags: java, android, performance, save, game-engine

As a hobby project I'm building a **2D** game with a **custom game engine** in Android. Currently I can render a json map, and let the user interact with objects on the map. The game should be an open world map, with multiple maps. One of my current maps has a 150 x 150 tile pattern, with on every tile one or more objects. Thus, the map has **22.500**, multiple layers, and more attributes. The player can edit objects (like fish in water object, plant seeds in soil, etc.), so every object needs to be stored separately. Some objects, like growing plants, **need to be updated over time**, even when the player is not playing the game.

My question is about efficiently **saving and loading** the game state. I think I need to store all the attributes of the maps, together with the objects, player progress, npc progress, and so on. Since this is a lot of data for a **mobile device**, I can't think of a good way to store this on the phone (or in the cloud).

I've tried the following:
- Store the entire game state in a **serialized** file. The parsing of this file took way to long while loading, and when one object's state changed, the whole game had to be loaded.
- Store every object in a **sqlite database**, with for every attribute a **column**. This was even slower than the first option, so not an option either.
- Store every object serialized as a **blob** in the database. This option wasn't much faster than the previous one.

I've been looking at **ObjectBox**, but in order to create the entity values for this database, I need to change a lot of reference values to ToOne<> or ToMany<> objects, which will take a lot of time and since I am using the map attributes to render the maps, the wrapping and unwrapping of the objects would cause (unnecessary) delay. (This is an assumption)

How do I save the game state without causing a 20-minute loading delay?

Comment: I think this question would better fit on [gamedev.se] since it's related to storing game data efficiently and not a direct programming issue.

Comment: Will do that! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First of all it really depends on your custom game engine and see how to load or initializing the game scenes. As you mentioned, you have too much data to save and restore, So avoid using database approaches because usually they are not efficient for this purposes.

If you want a fast solution, binary methods are better. Try to save your game data in binary chunks in the android data folder or assets then read and load them in initializing state without blocking other process (probably you need to separate loading assets thread).

You need game saving data structure and modify your custom game engine to load them step by step. for better performance check lazy loading technique.

I guess the serialized didn't work because it's trying to deserialize and restore everything in one step. See can you take apart your data or layers?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't exactly realized how you are working with your game engine and database. but just wanted to note that as long as you are using android, you can use SharedPreferences for keeping state. At least for some of your data.